# Is it possible to add comments to a csproj file?

Tags: csproj

Can you add comments to a .csproj file?  If so, what's the best way to do it?

Comment: haven't worked with .csproj files, but looking at this post http://westcountrydeveloper.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/querying-properties-within-csproj-files-using-xml/ XML comments should work?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Comments are written as usual in XML files:

```
<!-- comment -->
```

[How to: Write a Simple MSBuild Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171479%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: just making sure there wasn't some fancy, Microsoft-specific commenting style.  Thanks!

Comment: @gonzobrains I tried it, it worked, and *then* I did the google search that landed me here just because I still wasn't convinced I was doing it the Microsoft way.

Comment: Unless your comment contains `--` itself, then you have a whole other problem.

Answer (score 22):

The following works for multi-line comments.

```
<!-- 
  comment 1
  comment 2
  ....
-->
```